# applescript - quicktime 7 audio (wav) export

Tags: qt, audio, applescript

I'm working on a script to help my workflow. My work involves sound design, and I often have to take videos and extract the audio. Regardless of the source/compression, I like it in .wav format - best quality, accepted by all audio editing software, and least overhead for playback in a live environment.

Currently, I use Quicktime Pro 7's Export feature for this task - the current Quicktime X doesn't export to .wav. Built into the OS, so instead of using a separate tool, I'm using QT.

I am using Automator to write a service - select the file, open it in QT, export as wav and save it in the same location as the original, then quit. Here is what I have so far, and I keep getting an error. "The action “Run AppleScript” encountered an error." It compiles properly, but nothing comes out. Late last night I got it to spit out .mov files for some reason (despite trying to tell it wave) and now I can't even get back there.

Any help is appreciated. As you can see from the commented parts, I was trying to specify anywhere, since trying to make it the same location as the original was escaping me. Currently I'm just having it prompt me on where to save, so I can just tackle one problem at a time. Cheers!

```
tell application "QuickTime Player 7"
--set saveFile to POSIX path of (((path to desktop) as Wave) & "test.wav")
set outfile to choose file name with prompt "Save altered file here:"
set error_states to {load state unknown, load error}
set successful_states to {loaded, complete}
repeat until load state of first document is in (error_states & successful_states)
    delay 0.1
end repeat
tell document to save in outfile

if (load state of first document is in successful_states) then
    if (can export first document as wave) then
        export first document to outfile as wave
    else
        error "Cannot export " & (source_file as string) & " in .wav (Wave) format."
    end if
else
    error "File is not in a successful load state: " & (load state of first document as string)
end if
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

The file output should have '.wav" extension. To do so, I changed a bit your script and I remove the "tell document to save in outfile".
if you really want to delete your initial file after export, you need to add that at end of the script (I prefer to check the export is successful before deletion !).
Also, you must change the first line to replace the choose file (for my tests) to the read input variable from Automator service script :

```
set InFile to choose file "select video file for test only" -- to be replace by the input of your Automator Service

-- conversion of selected file with proper folder and new '.wav" extension
tell application "Finder"
set FFolder to (container of InFile) as string
set FName to name of InFile
set FExt to name extension of InFile
end tell
set Pos to offset of FExt in FName
if Pos > 0 then --change extension from current to 'wav'
set OutFile to FFolder & (text 1 thru (Pos - 1) of FName) & "wav"
else
set OutFile to FFolder & FName & ".wav"
end if

tell application "QuickTime Player 7"
activate
open InFile
set error_states to {load state unknown, load error}
set successful_states to {loaded, complete}
repeat until load state of first document is in (error_states & successful_states)
    delay 0.1
end repeat
if (load state of first document is in successful_states) then
    if (can export first document as wave) then
        export first document to OutFile as wave
    else
        error "Cannot export " & (source_file as string) & " in .wav (Wave) format."
    end if
else
    error "File is not in a successful load state: " & (load state of first document as string)
end if
end tell
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. I'm going to work on this again in a few days, but I wanted to make sure I said thank you for your time. I'll report back! Cheers.